# Class objects are irregular when assigning functions

Tags: python, function, functional-programming

Let's say I have a function like this:

```
def id(x):
  return x
```

I expect to be able to bind it to *any* object (let's say x),

```
x.f = id
```

and be able to do

```
x.f(1)
=> 1
```

However, classes are not regular objects because it does not work :

```
class X(object):
  pass

X.f = id
x.f(1)
=> unbound method f() must be called with X instance as first argument (got int instance instead)
```

So that I have to do,

```
X.f=staticmethod(id)
X.f(1)
=> 1
```

However it doesn't work with regular objects,

```
x.f=staticmethod(f)
x.f(1)
=> 'staticmethod' object is not callable
```

So is there a way to have assignment work as expected in generic code where
I do not know whether the object assigned to is a regular object of a class object
and when the assigned object may be a function?

Comment: You shouldn't override the built in `id()` method.

Comment: "I expect to be able to bind it to any object" Really?  Why?  Any link or quote that would set that expectation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import inspect
if inspect.isclass(X):
   X.f = staticmethod(f)
else:
   X.f = f
```

The issue isn't the assignment; that works fine. It is that functions on classes take `self` as their first parameter, and your function doesn't. You can get the actual function back with

```
X.__dict__['f']
<function f at 0x023A52F0>
```

or

```
X.f
<unbound method X.f>
X.f.im_func
<function f at 0x023A52F0>
```

(You are getting an unbound method instead of the original function, because in Python 2.x that is what happens when you access a method on a class. In Python 3.x that is changed and you just get the original function. I believe it is for backwards compatibility with old-style classes.)

---

This is a weird thing to want to do: you are working at a very high level of abstraction if you don't even know if the object you are working with is a class or not! For that matter, what if you get passed a built-in type, say a string? You can't set attributes on that! I think you need to work at a slightly lower level.

Comment: Indeed, with Python 3 the function is not turned into a bound function : "X.f=f" and "X.f(1)" => 1.

Comment: However, I don't think this as anything to do with compatibility with old style classes because old style classes behave the same as new style classes for the binding of functions.

Answer (score 1):

Define your function that you want to bind like this:

```
def id_(self, x):
    return x
```

and now you can do something like :

```
X.f = id_
x = X()
x.f(1)
=> 1
```

Comment: That's not the point. The point is that this should work _generically_, without having to modify the function. That's what the `staticmethod` call is for.

Comment: @katrielalex: i think that this should helpful to the OP because from his question i think he didn't understand why his first example was not working so he was thinking that he could use __staticmethod__ to fix that rather than just changing the function argument as shown above in my answer (monkey matching)

Comment: If x is a regular object, it will not work but lead to the error "f() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)" because f is not bound when assigned to a regular object.

Comment: @katrielalax: staticmethod can only be used if it is a class object and not a "regular" object.

Comment: @Eduardo : i can see now the point that you want to make ; and i will not suggest bounding a function to a regular object directly because simply there is not use of it because you don't have access to self (instance) and even if you use __staticmethod__, you have to know that __staticmethod__ are like regular module function , in the other hand the method in my answer can be useful when doing monkey patching (extending a class dynamically) , well hope it help :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree that this is fairly odd behavior. Perhaps there is a reason for this; perhaps it is one of those corner cases that never got fully investigated, or, if it was investigated, was considered so obscure as to not be worth addressing. Sometimes happens.

If you want the behavior that assigning a function as a class attribute always makes it a static method, you can do this with a metaclass.

```
class func2static(type):
    def __setattr__(cls, name, value):
        if type(value) is type(lambda: 0):
            value = staticmethod(value)
        type.__setattr__(cls, name, value)

class X(object):
    __metaclass__ = func2static
```

Now let's show that both the class and instances of the class can have a function assigned to them, which is then callable.

```
f = lambda x: x

X.f = f
X.f(3)  # no exception

x = X()    
x.g = f
x.g(3)  # also no exception
```

This doesn't really solve the problem if you are monkey-patching random classes defined in other modules, unfortunately, but you probably shouldn't be doing that anyway.  :-)